# Authenticate against UAG using Windows Phone 8 app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, httpwebrequest

I have a very simple scenario - I need my app to automatically authenticate against the UAG gateway. At the moment, I only have a file share application behind the portal, but I'm just trying to do an automatic authentication against the UAG by supplying the user credentials in code. I'm trying to access `portal.mylab.com/dummylink` - I know this will fail but I want the app to show me it passed the UAG authentication and failed when trying to find this dummylink application

What I have for now is simple, there is just a button in the WP8 app and everything else is hardcoded. I have a simple textblock under the button which shows the response from the website, but I get the authentication page everytime. This is what I have

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Uri targetUri = new System.Uri("portal.mylab.com/dummylink");
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(targetUri);
            request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

           request.Headers["User-Agent"] = "Microsoft Office Mobile";
           request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("testuser" + ":" + "Password1")) + System.Environment.NewLine;
request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(ReadWebRequestCallback), request);

}

private void ReadWebRequestCallback(IAsyncResult callbackResult)
        {
            HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)callbackResult.AsyncState;

            HttpWebResponse myResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myRequest.EndGetResponse(callbackResult);

using (StreamReader httpwebStreamReader = new StreamReader(myResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                string results = httpwebStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => TextBlockResults.Text = results);
            }
}
```

When I look at the textblock, I can see the HTML code being returned for the login page (for a mobile portal), with 2 buttons to login either using a PIN or using credentials. What I expected (or rather wanted) to see is UAG authorization to be successful and get some kind of a "dummylink page not found" type of error. I am supplying the user credentials to UAG but it doesn't seem to be picking them up.

I'm probably missing something very obvious here, and also this is my first time with anything to do with UAG, so please excuse stupid mistakes :)

Thanks in advance

Comment: This might be a useful source: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh180841.aspx

Comment: I've already read that and tried authenticating against the UAG using the method mentioned in the paper, but UAG doesn't authenticate the session :(

Comment: Turns out this approach is completely wrong! IF someone is looking on how to do the above, then please look at this brilliant blog http://usingnat.net/sharepoint/2011/2/23/how-to-programmatically-authenticate-to-uag-protected-sharep.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this approach is completely wrong! IF someone is looking on how to do the above, then please look at this brilliant blog

http://usingnat.net/sharepoint/2011/2/23/how-to-programmatically-authenticate-to-uag-protected-sharep.html